# Difference between Machine-oriented high-level language and high-level language

Tags: machine-code

I know that Babbage is a machine-oriented high-level language for the GEC 4080 series machines. What is the difference between Machine-oriented high-level language and high-level language?

Answer (score 1):

The [Babbage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babbage_(programming_language)) language is much more "machine-oriented" than it is "high-level", and it would be more accurate to describe it as a "[high-level assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_assembler)".

As such, the heart of the language consists of statements having a one-to-one correspondence with the machine code into which they directly assemble (as in any assembly language).  What makes this assembly language "high-level", then, is the addition of control statements for conditional branching and looping ("WHILE ... DO", "REPEAT ... WHILE", ... etc.).

However, this is in stark contrast to true "high-level" languages (such as [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)), and [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language))), where the "higher the level", the farther is the correspondence to the final machine code that results after compilation/assembly/linkage.

Even in languages such such as [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), which some have called a "glorified assembly language," the correspondence to the final machine code is still quite far from being "one-to-one."